# How to calculate range of data type eg int

Tags: c++, variables, int, size, formula

I want to know why in formula to calculate range of any data type
i.e.2^(n-1),why it is n-1 ,n is the number of bits occupied by the given data type

Comment: what is the range of numbers you can represent with 1 bit? That should answer your question

Comment: In the rare event that I need this information, I just have the language tell me the limits with this: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the type is unsigned, the maximum value is (2<sup>n</sup>)-1, because there are 2<sup>n</sup> values, and one of them is zero.
2<sup>(n-1)</sup> is the value of the n:th bit alone - bit 1 is 2<sup>0</sup>, bit 2 is 2<sup>1</sup>, and so on.

This is the same for any number base - in the decimal system, n digits can represent 10<sup>n</sup> different values, with the maximum value being 10<sup>n</sup>-1, and the n:th digit is "worth" 10<sup>(n-1)</sup>.

For example, the largest number with three decimal digits is 999 (that is, 10<sup>3</sup>-1), and the third decimal digit is "the hundreds digit", 10<sup>2</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

First `2^(n-1)` is not correct, the maximum (unsigned) number represented by the data type is:

```
max = 2^n - 1
```

So for a 8 Bit data type, the maximum represented value is `255`

`2^n` tells you the amount of numbers represented (`256` for the 8-Bit example) but because you want to include `0` the range is `0 to 255` and not `1 to 256`